# Adsense Is Not Working

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, adsense

I have a little problem with my adsense code that doesn't want to show up on my Wordpress site.
It is the first time that i got an adsense code in iframe.
So I'm completely new at this.
Here is the code:

```
iframe allowtransparency="true" src="thewebsite.com/ad.aspx?bid=7783&pid=2779907" width="980" height="240" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">/iframe>
```

And i want to place it in the head tag of my site but it's not showing up somehow.

Do you guys have any tricks or solution to make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you putting it in the head tag?

Comment: Because i want to have it on the top of my site.

Comment: Is that your actual code? There are multiple syntax errors / issues with what you've shared

Comment: The "head tag" as in `<head>..</head>`? Uhm, yeah, that won't show up anywhere within your site...

Comment: No. I have edited a few personal things out. But this is basically how the adsense code looks like.

Comment: yeah exactly in the head tag. It works if i put other adsense codes in there but it's not working with the iframe adsense code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `iframe` is specifically something that displays something visual on your site. In essence it embeds a remote resource, "another website", into your site. You need to put it exactly where you want it to appear. Putting it in the head means it's never going to visually show up anywhere. You need to place it somewhere in the `<body>`.

Comment: Hmm.. okey? and how do i actually do that? I'm afraid to mess the entire website up.

Comment: Were there absolutely no instructions accompanying that code snippet? Google Adsense Help would be my first try for implementation details.

Comment: No instructions at all unfortunately. I have now tried to put the code in one of my wix.com sites instead. And it works perfectly, but not on wordpress sites :/

Answer (score 0):

@deceze gave you very good technical explanation, but there is another problem: we are not allowed to place AdSense ads in (i)frames.

> Is it violating program policy if I place ads on iframe webpages in my
>   software?
>
> Yes, it does violate our policies. Firstly, you’re not allowed to
>   place ads in a frame within another page. Exceptions to our policies
>   are permitted only with authorization from Google for the valid use of
>   iframes. Secondly, you’re not allowed to put ads in your software,
>   e.g., if you control both a website with ads and an app that loads
>   that website, we will take action against it.

AdSense policy FAQs > Part 2: Ad implementation
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en#2

http://adsense.blogspot.rs/2011/06/clarifying-our-ad-implementation.html

Comment: It's not an ads from Google AdSense we are talking about.